# How do you upload Laravel to godaddy's web hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, web-hosting

I am trying to create a basic login setup through Laravel.  I used the following guide to help me get started:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-and-easy-laravel-login-authentication

After completing the steps, I used this guide to help me upload the files to godaddy's web hosting services:
https://medium.com/@kunalnagar/deploying-laravel-5-on-godaddy-shared-hosting-888ec96f64cd

I followed the guide to the letter but I'm still having some issues.  After I moved the content of the "public" folder to the public_html folder and left the remaining files in the Laravel folder which was located in the home directory, it was supposed to allow me to type in:mydomain.com/awesomeproject and see the laravel login that was created.  Instead it loads to a blank page.  Here are pictures of what I am referring to:
[image]

[image]

I might be messing up the following step:
[image]

Because when it asks me to change the path to reflect a new directory, I'm not sure exactly how that's setup.  This is the current path that I put:

```
require __DIR__.'/../Laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../Laravel/bootstrap/start.php';
```

The autoload.php and the start.php files are located in Laravel->html->bootstrap.  I'm not sure if this has something to do with it.  Theoretically after doing these steps correctly I should be able to see my laravel application on my domain but so far I've only gotten a blank screen.  I'm very new to these things so I don't know how much of this I am getting totally wrong.  I essentially just want to get this login thing working on my site using laravel.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

These screenshots show the contents of the Laravel folder and the content of the html folder within the Laravel folder.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show me the content of the `Laravel` folder on the Go Daddy host?

Comment: Which version of laravel?

Comment: It's Laravel Version 4.1.26.  I will screenshot the Laravel folder momentarily.  Thanks.